# Customizable SVG editor for web site

Tags: image, svg, editor

Scenario: User pick from predefined maps. User add markings, drawings, text. User generated map is stored. Others may view it.

Q: What good solutions for such SVG editor are there?

Details:
Mobile support would be nice, but not necessary. Would like to store maps as images, and combine them with user markings (stored as SVG) on client side letter, to save bandwidth and storage space. I need to limit SVG options (like limiting colours to just few, lines to just few specific styles, and some pre-set icons, etc.) So customized menus are at premium. And at some point in time, I may need to convert that SVG to some other format, so clean SVG output is also important.

Comment: I think the question is too nailed down and no example code etc to be useful. Only thing I would possibly suggest is customising http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ or look at some of the projects based from that.

Comment: hehe. Too much details? ;) List of features by svg-edit is ... SO BIG. I would spent too much time hacking features OUT. But if that's the only way to go... (then put Your comment as answer so I can OK it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I know of that could be useful is SVG Edit. It doesn't fit the requirements without quite a bit of work though I think, but if you know Javascript well it may not be too daunting. Its over at http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ .

There's a list of projects off it here http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/wiki/ProjectsThatUseSvgEdit which could be useful as well.

Comment: Found SVG-Edit but its full blown SVG editor. But it seam to be only option out there...